# Make GET request using cURL

Tags: php, curl, httprequest, libcurl

I'm trying to make a simple GET request using cURL directly but I'm not able to get the response.

```
public function getSiteLicenses($page = 1) {

        $url = 'https://testdomain.com';
        $header = array('Key:somekey');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return  json_decode($response, true);
    }
```

The alternate way for me is to use some HTTP library, which works fine but I want to avoid using the library and use cURL directly.

```
 public function getSiteLicenses($page = 1) {

        $url = 'https://testdomain.com';

        $siteLicenses = \Httpful\Request::get($url)
                ->addHeader("KEY", $this->apikey)
                ->send();
        $siteLicensesArray = json_decode($siteLicenses, true);
        return $siteLicensesArray;
    }
```

What am I missing for requesting GET method using cURL directly? Thanks

Comment: I'd say strip this down, and start off with a basic cURL get request as shown in the manual.  If that does not work then look at whether cURL is enabled. If it does work, then your add lines in one at a time till you get to where you want to, or you discover the setting that is letting you down. Incremental development I think its called.